# fromTo mapping in Reactive systems

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactive, flux

Is it reasonable to implement dynamic fromTo mapping(listening for changes) in reactive manner? Possible solutions:

- old fashion blocking style
- cache like Caffeine, etc.
- Collections.synchronizedList<Mono<Pair<String, String>>> and process it in a stream

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what do you exactly search for. It is possible to use Project Reactor with Spring Integration, and it seems like the solution for you. You can see [some examples here](https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-integration-reactor-kafka).